# how replace null characters in UNIX?

Tags: linux, shell, cat

I had this string and to show the special characters and then replace

```
0|A0140017511|1|DEMÁS TEMAS|�|�|2014-08-01
```

I want this

```
 0|A0140017511|1|DEMÁS TEMAS|@|@|2014-08-01
```

`$ xxd -p file.txt`

```
307c41303134303031373531317c317c44454dc381532054454d41537c00
7c007c323031342d30382d3031
```

Comment: Can you also add the output of `xxd -p file.txt` to your question? So we can generate your input without losing foreign characters.

Comment: already add the `xxd -p file.txt`

Comment: does it have to be `^@`? Is a single character also okay, like `@` for instance?

Comment: any text helps me to replace it

Comment: Is this an XY question for "How do I remove/replace NUL bytes in a string"?

Comment: @thatotherguy yes, of course :), that my problem

Comment: @thatotherguy reformulate the question :)

Answer (score 2):

From `xxd`'s output I can tell that you're trying to replace `NUL`s with something else. To replace them with a single character, for example `-`, use `tr`:

```
$ tr '\0' '-' < file
0|A0140017511|1|DEMÁS TEMAS|-|-|2014-08-01
```

Or if you have GNU sed, you can use a string as well:

```
$ sed 's/\x0/^@/g' file
0|A0140017511|1|DEMÁS TEMAS|^@|^@|2014-08-01
```